# Openlayers selection

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, latitude-longitude, select

Is it possible to select a polygon from a predefined Lat & Lon programmatically?

eg location point: x='1234' y='5678' intersects polygon '1234', therefore SELECT POLYGON '1234'

So far I have managed to get the lat lon of the drop point:

```
$( "#cow" ).draggable({ revert: true});
        $( "#map" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {          
    var point = map.getLonLatFromPixel( map.events.getMousePosition(event, ui   ))     
        OpenLayers.Util.getElement("pos").innerHTML = point


        }
        });
```

Now I just neeed to select the polygon that x and y intersect. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the code:

```
  $( "#cow" ).draggable({ revert: true});
    $( "#map" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var farmid = 448; 
    var point = map.getLonLatFromPixel( map.events.getMousePosition(event, ui ) )
    var lon =  point.lon.toFixed(3);
    var lat =   point.lat.toFixed(3);
    var dropPosition = point.lon.toFixed(3) + ' ' + point.lat.toFixed(3);

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../php/position.php", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'farmid':'"+ farmid +"', 'position':'"+ dropPosition +"'}",
    success: function(returnval){ 

    var pid = parseInt(returnval); 
    var selectB = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([farmbounds]);
    for(var f=0;f<farmbounds.features.length;f++) {
                                    if(farmbounds.features[f].fid == 'farmpaddocks.'+pid+'') {
                                selectB.select(farmbounds.features[f]);
break;
  }}
}//success
});//ajax
}
});
```

And the php file looks like this:

```
<?php 
$farmid= $_GET["farmid"];
$position = $_GET["position"];
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgis user=aaaaa password=bbbbb" ); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM public.farmpaddocks WHERE farmid = '$farmid' AND st_contains(farmpaddocks.the_geom,ST_GeomFromText('POINT($position)',3111)) ='t'";
$resultD = pg_query($db,$sql); 
while($rowD=pg_fetch_row($resultD))  
{ 
$paddockid= $rowD[0];
echo $paddockid;
}

?>
```